# JSON won`t get parsed with variables out of an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I don´t understand why my JSON doesn´t get parsed. I hope someone could explain this to me. I try to send a JSON from PHP to JavaScript.

**This code works fine:**

From PHP

```
echo json_encode(array($row['jobunique'], $row['jobtitle']));
```

to JavaScript

```
success: function(getjoblist) {

        var getjobdetails = $.parseJSON(getjoblist); 
}
```

**But this code gives me an error back:**

From PHP - data comes out of an array

```
echo json_encode(array($data[2], $data[3]));
```

I thought, maybe it's an object and I need to make a string out of the variables like this:

```
echo json_encode(array(strval($data[2]), strval($data[3])));
```

But it did not work either.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
success: function(callback) {

    var namearray = $.parseJSON(callback);
}
```

**Here is the error from the console:**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Here is the network-tab:

[image: picture]

Comment: Check the "Network" tab in Chrome dev tools to see contents of the server's response.

Comment: That error normally happens when there's an error from your server side or wrong json format from server.. check the response in the network tab

Comment: I added a picture of it. What should I see? :)

Comment: Please, show the output

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer go to network tab click on config.php then click on response you will see the server output then you will see that it's invalid json

Comment: The response is: ["Fabi","Squinobal"] - What should valid json look like?

Comment: Valid JSON should look like `{ "Name": "Fabi", "Description": "Squinobal" }` or something

Comment: And how I get my json to look like that? :D - I quit programming right now... why did i start.. omg

Comment: Can you tell me please, what the difference between the first example and the second is? The first works, like I said.

Comment: It depends on what both of your examples output and the values. Try adding `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to include the array keys (0, 1 etc) `echo json_encode(array($data[2], $data[3]), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);`

Comment: Are you sure it's the *only* thing in the output? Because that's valid json. So no extraneous `"`s or extra brackets?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - I updated the picture so you can see.

Comment: I'm at a loss. It works on my machine. Please note that `parseJSON` is deprecated. Out of curiosity, try the following: before parsing, do `console.log(callback)` and check if the consol shows what you expect. Also, try using the browser's native `JSON.parse` instead.

Comment: As an aside, `callback` is a very bad name for what is actually data.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - ["Fabi", "Squinobal"]
0: "Fabi"
1: "Squinobal"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)

Comment: I have the failure. It was "dataType: 'json'" - in my ajax request. Can you explain to me why, please?

Comment: @Andreasschnetzer Kalmár's answers below explains it pretty well, IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `callback` variable is already an array. JQuery's AJAX methods automatically parse responses, if there are JSON specific headers present (Content-type: application/json).

Try run `JSON.parse(["Fabi","Squ"])` in the console, it will get you the same error message.

Read more about this at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ :

`dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).`